# Can I change port of exit after Schengen Visa issuance?

Tags: schengen, europe, schengen-visas, itineraries, schedule-change

I have received my Type C Multiple entry visa from Slovenia, for a month, in my itinerary I mentioned I will leave Schengen area for Turkey,on 17th Day, from Krakow. Since, I have a month Visa, now I am planning to instead travel in Europe only, go to Croatia or Greece (not in my itinerary)rather than Turkey, since I want my last leg of travel in a beach destination. Can I all together remove Turkey from my plan and may be change my exit port to Greece or Croatia?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing because it seems to equate Turkey, Croatia, and Greece, but Turkey and Croatia are not part of the Schengen area, and Greece is.  Also, it's not clear why you consider Turkey not to be a beach destination: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=turkey+beaches&hps=1&ia=images&iax=images

Comment: Yes, I understand, Croatia is not a part of Schengen, so in a way I would leave Schengen while entering Croatia, so that is same thing as going to Turkey. So, in any case can I do that, changing my onward country? if I leave Schengen on the same day as per my itinerary but change my destination. Also, I want to drop turkey because, I have to get an e-visa, even with a Schengen but in case of Croatia it's visa free and also I kind of feeling an urge to see Croatia.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As long as you leave the Schengen area at the end of your trip, I don't think anyone will care what you do.

Comment: This is a dangerous answer, as in some cases it is rather dangerous for future visa applications, and in the worst cases they can not allow you to enter the Schengen area or send you home when found out.

Answer (score 5):

I mostly agree with the answer by [Henrik](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175186/can-i-change-port-of-exit-after-schengen-visa-issuance/175194#175194), but consider this:

- You may **change details** of your itinerary after the visa was issued, as long as the premise of the application remains the same and as long as you meet the maximum days, earliest entry and latest exit, number of entries, etc.
- You must not **misrepresent** your itinerary during the visa application, in the hope that the lies will make it easier to get the visa.

From that follows a third point:

- You should avoid **giving the impression** that you lied by excessive changes to your itinerary.

Going directly home, instead of the planned last leg of the journey, would be no problem at all.

Traveling through a different, unplanned Schengen state on your way to or from the main destination is not a problem as long as it sounds plausible. For instance, if you had planned to enter France and then go to Germany for a conference, and then get a better flight through the Netherlands, you can skip France and enter through the Netherlands instead.

Coming *and* leaving a week later than planned should be no problem, if the visa had enough validity. Business meetings and vacations get re-scheduled all the time.

But almost doubling the planned duration (17 days to 30 days) looks bad.